# Hard drive not showing in BIOS, works in another PC

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, motherboard, bios

I have 2 Samsung 2TB F3 hard drives. These are in a Windows 8 system and they were both spanned to create a single 4TB Spanned Volume.

I deleted this spanned volume and formatted each drive with just a Simple Volume. The drives continue to work in this PC.

However, the drives are not showing in either Windows 8 or the BIOS or another PC build. Other drives work in this new PC build, and using different SATA ports and cables used for the other working drives do not solve the issue.

What is my next troubleshooting step?

Comment: The system where the HDDs work? Does it use BIOS or UEFI firmware?

Comment: Hi, Both are UEFI.

Comment: Did you already try some live-CD environment (some Linux distribution or Hiren's boot CD) and do a **low level format** of your drive? Formatting it in Windows might leave some information in the MBR. Also a good idea to wipe the MBR before formatting it again.

Answer (score -1):

I would check SATA RAID/IDE/AHCI settings in BIOS. Also the PC that does not detect drives might have an issue with the speed of the serial ata bus. Some HDD's have a jumper to switch the speed to 150 MBs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Specifically what settings am I looking for, what settings would I expect to see? I see an option in the BIOS to switch to RAID, IDE or AHCI modes but nothing in terms of specific settings for them.

Comment: I would just make sure each pc is set to the same thing in the BIOS regarding SATA/IDE/RAID/AHCI function. It is a long shot, but worth a try.

Comment: OK, had a look in both BIOS and I can see that the old PC is set to use IDE, and again I can't really see any settings specific to each mode, only which mode to use - but the new PC is set to ACHI.

If I switch to IDE, then the drive does still not appear.

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of the motherboard or chipset perhaps. I would check to see if the HDD has any pins on it for jumpers. Lookup the schematics/pinout or jumper settings for that hdd online. Maybe that is the issue. Otherwise consider a PCI/X sata/raid card, or external solution like USB or eSATA. This is all assuming you mean the BIOS does not detect, and not the OS. If it is the OS I would make sure the disk is marked as active with `diskpart` then `list disk` (if disk is there, then) `sel disk #` and then `active` and/or update motherboard/chipset drivers. Good luck! :)

Comment: Just found this - looks like this might be the cause, the motherboard is a H97, so could affect H67 onwards I guess... http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223631en I will give it a go!

Comment: OK that worked, excellent stuff! Learned some things from you though so whilst not applicable here maybe one day it will be! Thanks.